# Slugfy em query FLASK

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Estou tentando dar um slug em um dado, tentei usar o lower e o replace para trocar alguns caracteres, minha query é parecida com isso:

```
return Person.query.get(person_id).name.filter(func.lower(func.replace(Person.name, "ç", "c"))
```

funciona, mas se eu receber algo como `'á'`, ou algum outro caracter especial, ele quebra, obviamente.

Qual é a maneira de contorna isso, fazer uma lista com todos caracteres com o index para dar um replace? algo assim?